# Using Subtract layer in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I'm implementing in Keras the LSTM architecture described [here](http://nlp.cs.rpi.edu/paper/multilingualmultitask.pdf). I think I am really close, though I still have a problem with the combination of the shared and language-specific layers. Here is the formula (approximately): `y = g * y^s + (1 - g) * y^u`

And here is the code I tried:

```
### Linear Layers ###
univ_linear = Dense(50, activation=None, name='univ_linear')
univ_linear_en = univ_linear(en_encoded)
univ_linear_es = univ_linear(es_encoded)
print(univ_linear_en)

# Gate >> g
gate_en = Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', name='gate_en')(en_encoded)
gate_es = Dense(50, activation='sigmoid', name='gate_es')(es_encoded)
print(gate_en)
print(gate_es)

# EN >> y^s
spec_linear_en = Dense(50, activation=None, name='spec_linear_en') (en_encoded)
print(spec_linear_en)

# g * y^s
gated_spec_linear_en = Multiply()([gate_en, spec_linear_en])
print(gated_spec_linear_en)

# ES >> y^s
spec_linear_es = Dense(50, activation=None, name='spec_linear_es')(es_encoded)
print(spec_linear_es)

# g * y^s
gated_spec_linear_es = Multiply()([gate_es, spec_linear_es])
print(gated_spec_linear_es)

# 1 - Gate >> (1 - g)
only_ones_en = K.ones(gate_en.shape)
univ_gate_en = Subtract()([only_ones_en, gate_en])
print(univ_gate_en)

only_ones_es = K.ones(gate_es.shape)
univ_gate_es = Subtract()([only_ones_es, gate_es])
print(univ_gate_es)

# (1 - g) * y^u
gated_univ_linear_en = Multiply()([univ_gate_en, univ_linear_en])
print(gated_univ_linear_en)
gated_univ_linear_es = Multiply()([univ_gate_es, univ_linear_es])
print(gated_univ_linear_es)

out_en = Add()([gated_spec_linear_en, gated_univ_linear_en])
print(out_en)

out_es = Add()([gated_spec_linear_es, gated_univ_linear_es])
print(out_es)
```

When I compile my model, I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Though, my model compiles without error when I replace `(1 - g) * y^u` by `g * y^u`:

```
# (1 - g) * y^u
gated_univ_linear_en = Multiply()([gate_en, univ_linear_en])
print(gated_univ_linear_en)
gated_univ_linear_es = Multiply()([gate_es, univ_linear_es])
print(gated_univ_linear_es)
```

Consequently, I think the problem comes from the code under the comment `# 1 - Gate >> (1 - g)`, and more precisely from the subtraction `(1 - g)`.

Does anyone have any clue about what exactly the problem is and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input of a Keras layer must be Keras Tensors which are the output of previous layers. When you write `only_ones_en = K.ones(gate_en.shape)`, then `only_ones_en` would not be a Keras Tensor, rather it would be a Tensor of the backend (e.g. TensorFlow Tensor).

As for your specific example, you can do this much more easily using a `Lambda` layer:

```
univ_gate_en = Lambda(lambda x: 1. - x)(gate_en)
```

Or maybe in a less efficient way:

```
univ_gate_en = Lambda(lambda x: K.ones_like(x) - x)(gate_en)
```

Or in a much more verbose and maybe less efficient way:

```
only_ones_en = Lambda(lambda x: K.ones_like(x))(gate_en)
univ_gate_en = Subtract()([only_ones_en, gate_en])
```

The same thing applies to other places where you have used `K.*` **as input of a layer**.