# Concatenate input tensor with multiple of neg 1 tensors

Tags: keras, tf.keras

**Similar Posts:** Firstly, these 2 posts are similar if not the same. I tried to implement these in vain. So I'm missing something probably because of my inexperience in Keras.
[similar 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254513/concatenate-input-with-constant-vector-in-keras-how-one-define-the-batch-size) ,
[similar 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254513/concatenate-input-with-constant-vector-in-keras-how-one-define-the-batch-size)

**The problem:**
I have a data generator to feed data into various models to evaluate model performance and to learn Keras.

```
model.fit_generator(generator=img_gen.next_train(), ....
```

One of the inputs produced by this generator is a tensor "labels" of shape=[batch_size, num_letters]. This tensor is the first input to

```
K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, ....
```

similar to [image_ocr.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/image_ocr.py) line 369.

The above "keras example" creates an RNN/GRU where each output step of the RNN is one input to the ctc, where there are num_letters steps in the RNN and the labels is of shape (?, num_letters). This worked fine for the first 6 models I have tested so far.

I am testing a new model where each step of the RNN/GRU output is "1 to n" inputs to the ctc and leaving it to training to optimize the output of each step.  So my ctc needs as it's first input  a tensor of shape=(?,num_letters*n) but the data generator produces shape=(?, num_letters).

Side note: The RNN in my model actually produce as a whole shape=(?, n, num_letters).  I know how to convert this to (?, n*num_letters).

**Solution 1** is a hack, change the generator so that it's unique for this model being tested. This generator will produce tensors of shape=(?,num_letters*n).  I don't like this because the generator is also being evaluated and would like it to be constant for each model being evaluated.

**Solution 2** is a hack, create a generator that encapsulates the original generator and augments the produced output.

**Solution 3:** have the model take an input of shape=(?, num_letters) and concatenate the necessary padding so the shape is (?,num_letters*n) that the ctc wants.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
num_letters = 3
n = 5

keras_tensor_input = keras.layers.Input( shape=[num_letters], dtype='float32' )
print("keras_tensor_input = ", keras_tensor_input)
# keras_tensor_input =  Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
# note ? is batch size

keras_tensor_neg_1 = keras.backend.constant( -1, dtype='float32', shape=[num_letters] )
print("keras_tensor_neg_1 = ", keras_tensor_neg_1)
# keras_tensor_neg_1 =  Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
# note no batch size

keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled = keras.backend.tile(keras_tensor_neg_1, (n-1))
print("keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled = ", keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled)
# keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled =  Tensor("Tile_2:0", shape=(12,), dtype=float32)
# note no batch size, but now the correct fill length

# FAILED attempt to put in a batch size

layer_const_neg_1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled ,output_shape=[(n-1)*num_letters] )
keras_tensor_neg_1_prime = layer_const_neg_1(keras_tensor_neg_1)
print("keras_tensor_neg_1_prime = ", keras_tensor_neg_1_prime)
# keras_tensor_neg_1_prime =  Tensor("Tile_2:0", shape=(12,), dtype=float32)

# CRASH AT NEXT STEP BECAUSE NO ? in keras_tensor_neg_1_prime

# concatenate the input from the generator and the padding
keras_tensor_concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()( inputs = [keras_tensor_input, keras_tensor_neg_1_prime] )
print("keras_tensor_concat = ", keras_tensor_concat)

my_model = keras.models.Model( inputs=[keras_tensor_input], output=keras_tensor_concat)

# dummy optimizer, loss, and metric just to allow compile to pass
my_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# a batch of size 1, for a tensor of shape =[3]
d1 = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]])

out = my_model.predict( [ d1 ] )
print(out)
```

**Notes:**

1. could have made constant shape=[num_letters*(n-1)] and drop the tile, but the same problem of missing batch size remains.
2. if I place batch_size as first dimensions, then it still fails complaining of (?, 3) can not be concatenated with (1, 12)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for a model that takes in

```
# a batch of size 1, for a tensor of shape =[3]
d1 = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

and produces as output

```
out = my_model.predict( [ d1 ] )
print(out)
# [[ 1.  2.  3. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]]
```

The big lesson is that **keras.layers** want as input, the output of other **keras.layers**.  So functionality from **keras.backend** like **tile** must be wrapped in **keras.layers.Lambda** before feeding them as input to **keras.layer**.

Thank you to

- [Stackoverflow: How to use tile function in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250533/how-to-use-tile-function-in-keras)
- [github issue: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11811)
- [Stackoverflow: Using Subtract layer in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865471/using-subtract-layer-in-keras)

**Here is the solution:**

```
# instantiate a Keras tensor ... as per document https://keras.io/layers/core/
keras_tensor_input = keras.layers.Input( shape=[num_letters], dtype='float32' )
print("keras_tensor_input = ", keras_tensor_input)
# keras_tensor_input =  Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865471/using-subtract-layer-in-keras
keras_tensor_neg_1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: -keras.backend.ones_like(x) )(keras_tensor_input)
print("keras_tensor_neg_1 = ", keras_tensor_neg_1)
# keras_tensor_neg_1 =  Tensor("lambda_1/Neg:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32)
# note batch size, just like keras_tensor_input

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250533/how-to-use-tile-function-in-keras
keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.tile(x, (1, n-1)))(keras_tensor_neg_1)
print("keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled = ", keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled)
# keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled =  Tensor("Tile_2:0", shape=(12,), dtype=float32)
# note batch size, just like keras_tensor_input

# concatenate the input from the generator and the padding
keras_tensor_concat = keras.layers.Concatenate()( inputs = [keras_tensor_input, keras_tensor_neg_1_tiled] )
print("keras_tensor_concat = ", keras_tensor_concat)
# keras_tensor_concat =  Tensor("concatenate_1/concat:0", shape=(?, 15), dtype=float32)

my_model = keras.models.Model( inputs=keras_tensor_input, output=keras_tensor_concat)

# dummy optimizer, loss, and metric so I can compile and test the model
my_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# a batch of size 1, for a tensor of shape =[3]
d1 = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3]])

out = my_model.predict( [ d1 ] )
print(out)
# [[ 1.  2.  3. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]]
```